# Selected Icon Not being Applied on WPF App

Tags: .net, wpf, application-icon

I have changed the icon in the Main Project Properties Icon and Manifest option. Yet, after running the App, the default Icon is what shows up.

Any idea why such odd behavior will occur?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Does the default icon show up in the explorer or does it show up in the taskbar buttons? In case of the latter: change the icon for the forms as well, as the task bar button icon is not retrieved from the exe file, but from the form's `Icon` property.

For WPF applications, use the attribute

```
Icon="Images\Logo.ico"
```

for the `Window` element in XAML to have the window show the icon.

Comment: It doesn't show up anywhere. I forgot to add, its a WPF application. Will edit my question soon.

Comment: If you select the ICO file in the project properties under "Symbol & Manifest" (not sure whether that's the name in English - I'm using German VS2010), after a recompile the EXE should have the icon (which you can verify in the Explorer. To use it for the WPF window, use something `Icon="Images\Logo.ico"` as an attribute for the window.

Comment: It's actually Icon and Manifest :). And the part about Icon did the Job. Thanks. Please consider editing your answer to include that so it can be treated as direct answer to my question.

Answer (score 11):

The icon doesn't show in debug / release mode, you need to run the application using ctrl+F5, [source](http://www.broculos.net/2014/03/wpf-how-to-add-icon-for-entire.html#.V1c7i-Z97tQ)